# How to remove ALL entries in a dictionary with the same value and get the number of entries removed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say that I have a dictionary like `{'Alice':'P-1', 12:'F-1', 17:'P-1', 'Bob':'F-1', 19:'T'}`. In this case same values would mean 'P-1' and 'F-1'. And 4 entries are removed. I wonder how can I write my codes so that it is effecient and can deal with very large dictionaries (like dozens of duplicate values).

Comment: What should be the result??? IOW, are you keeping one of the values, or removing *all* values.... giving you a final result of `{19:'T'}`?

Comment: The function I am constructing should return 4 while the dictionary after modification should be {19:'T'} .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that does what you want:

```
>>> import collections
>>> def remove_duplicates(d):
...     grouper = collections.defaultdict(list)
...     for k, v in d.items():
...         grouper[v].append(k)
...     total = 0
...     for val, keys in grouper.items():
...         if len(keys) > 1:
...             for k in keys:
...                 del d[k]
...             total += len(keys)
...     return total
...
>>> d = {'Alice':'P-1', 12:'F-1', 17:'P-1', 'Bob':'F-1', 19:'T'}
>>> remove_duplicates(d)
4
>>> d
{19: 'T'}
```

It works in linear time, but requires linear space. Personally, I would create a new dictionary instead of modifying the original, but that is what the above does.

Comment: @PeterJiang it creates a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a `list` factory.

Comment: @juanpa - Thanks for correcting me. I deleted my post.

Comment: @Transhuman you can still salvage it, just note, get `counts = Counter(dct.values())` then something like `{k:v for v in dct.items() if counts[v] <= 1}`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = {'Alice':'P-1', 12:'F-1', 17:'P-1', 'Bob':'F-1', 19:'T'}
removal_count = len([b for a, b in s.items() if b[-1].isdigit() and [re.findall('\d+$', c) for c in s.values()].count(re.findall('\d+$', b)) > 1])
print(removal_count)
```

Output:

```
4
```

To filter the dictionary:

```
new_s = {a:b for a, b in s.items() if [re.findall('\d+$', c) for c in s.values()].count(re.findall('\d+$', b)) <= 1}
```

Output:

```
{19: 'T'}
```